# MVC3 Async jQuery progress bar on a insert query

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous, progress

So I am trying to add an async progress bar on a really slow and long query that inserts a bunch of rows to a database. My implementation is based off this example: http://blog.janjonas.net/2012-01-02/asp_net-mvc_3-async-jquery-progress-indicator-long-running-tasks

Here is the javascript code for the progress bar

```
function updateMonitor(taskId, status) {
        $("#" + taskId).html("Task [" + taskId + "]: " + status);
    }
//other code
if (doSend == true) {
            $.post("/SendBatch/HandleBatchRequest", {
                //other code
            },
            function (taskId) {

                // Init monitors
                //breakpoint here does not stop it, it never enters this somehow?
                $("#monitors").append($("<p id='" + taskId + "'/>"));
                updateMonitor(taskId, "Started");

                // Periodically update monitors
                var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
                    $.post("SendBatch/Progress", { id: taskId }, function (progress) {
                    if (progress >= 100) {
                        updateMonitor(taskId, "Completed");
                        clearInterval(intervalId);
                    } else {
                        updateMonitor(taskId, progress + "%");
                    }
                });
            }, 100);
        }       
        ,"html");
```

Then there is the DIV within the display part of the website

```
<div id="monitors"></div>
```

Here is how the controller looks

```
public SendBatchController
    //some code
private static IDictionary<Guid, int> tasks = new Dictionary<Guid, int>();

public ActionResult HandleBatchRequest(
        //some code
    )
    {
        var taskId = Guid.NewGuid();
        tasks.Add(taskId, 0);



        var batchId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        var costd = cost.ToDecimal();

        IEnumerable<BatchListModel> customers;

        try
        {
            customers = new CustomerService(_customerRepository.Session).GetCustomers(
                //some code
                );
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            return Json(err.Message);
        }
        if (doSend)
        {
            var sent = 0;

            foreach (var c in customers)
            {
                try
                {
                    var usr = _customerRepository.LoadByID(c.ID);

                    var message = new ComLog
                                      {
                                          //insertions to log
                                      };

                    _comLogRepository.Save(message);
                    sent++;

                    //progress bar part inside here that is important comes here:
                    tasks[taskId] = sent;

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.WriteLine("ERR:" + e);
                }

                tasks.Remove(taskId);

            }
            return Json(taskId);

        }

        return Json(customers.Count() + " customers");
    }

    public ActionResult Progress(Guid id)
    {
        return Json(tasks.Keys.Contains(id) ? tasks[id] : 100);
    }
```

This does not work. The process works in the background. It is only the div that never shows up and never gives any indication. I know this is a lot of code to read but I am really stuck and would love some input on how to fix this.

Comment: I still can't get this to work. The div does not give any invormation during the query, but when the query is finnished it gives a confirmation that it is "Completed". I think the problem lies in the fact that "$.post("/SendBatch/HandleBatchRequest", {
                //other code
            }," has to be done before it goes into the "function (taskId) {" bracket. With a breakpoint inside the fuction (taskId) it confirms my theory, but I do not know how to fix it. I am not even sure if I understand how/if this method knows the total of queries that will be done so can't show "percent done".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try change your `updateMonitor` function into this :

```
function updateMonitor(taskId, status) {
    $("#monitors").html("Task [" + taskId + "]: " + status);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I can see the div and it's "Task ["7575d90d-12e2-4cbc-9263-61b7e4e222bc"]: Started". It does not quite work yet, but I should be able to fix it in due time.